# Online options to Run Jupyter notebook

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

What online services can I run a Jupyter notebook besides Google Colab? I’m certainly willing to pay for the use. I will need access to GPU and the script will need to run for at least 24 hours.

Comment: You seem linked to Azure. That is one that has GPUs. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-gpu). You can get GPUs with Machines on AWS or Google Cloud and install Jupyter and use it. Most of the big cloud providers also also already set up instances of Jupyter, too. HuggingFace allows you Jupyter with GPU, too.

Comment: check https://datasciencenotebook.org/jupyter-notebook-online and https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-online/

Answer (score 0):

For running Jupyter notebooks online with GPU access and the capability to run scripts for extended periods, such as at least 24 hours, there are several services available besides Google Colab. These services range from fully managed Jupyter notebook environments to cloud computing platforms where you can set up Jupyter notebooks on virtual machines with GPU support. Here's a list of options, including both free and paid services:

1. Microsoft Azure Notebooks now integrated with Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML)
2. Amazon Web Services (AWS) through Amazon SageMaker
3. Google Cloud Platform (GCP) via Google Cloud offers AI Platform Notebooks
4. IBM Watson Studio
5. Kaggle Kernels, a subsidiary of Google, offers free access to computing resources including GPUs and TPUs through its Kaggle Kernels service.
6. Hugging Face Spaces
7. Paperspace Gradient
8. DeepNote which is a new generation of Jupyter notebook with real-time collaboration.

As I said, Microsoft Azure Notebooks now integrated with Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML) which offers an integrated environment for managing datasets, running Jupyter notebooks, training machine learning models, and deploying AI solutions.

Here's how to set up a Jupyter notebook in Azure through Azure Machine Learning:

1. **Sign in to the Azure Portal**: Go to [https://portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com/) and sign in with your Microsoft account.
2. **Create a New Resource**: Click on “Create a resource” and search for “Machine Learning” in the marketplace. Select “Machine Learning” and click "Create".
3. **Configure the Workspace**: Provide the necessary details such as subscription, resource group (create a new one if necessary), workspace name, and the region. Then click "Review + create" and finally "Create" to deploy the workspace.
   [image]

Once the workspace is created, you can access Azure Machine Learning Studio by navigating to your resource in the Azure Portal and clicking on “Launch studio” to open Azure Machine Learning Studio in a new browser tab.

In Azure Machine Learning Studio:

1. **Open Compute**: Go to the “Compute” section in the sidebar.
2. **Create a New Compute Instance**: Click on “+ New” in the Compute Instances tab.
   [image]
3. **Configure the Compute Instance**: Name your instance, select the virtual machine size (including GPU options as you mentioned), and then click "Create". This may take a few minutes.
   [image]

Since you want for 24 hours you can configure it accordingly or set schedule as shown below-
[image]
Once the compute instance is ready:

1. **Open Jupyter**: Navigate to the “Compute” section, find your compute instance, and click on “Jupyter” or “JupyterLab” to open the Jupyter interface in a new browser tab.
   [image]

[image]